# Close IE specific window with C# using Kill is not working

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, forceclose

I am trying to close the most recent window/tab of IE but when I call the Kill method the window relaunches without the content of the page.
This is the code that I use to get the most recent IE process:

```
var a = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore");
DateTime earliestStart = DateTime.Today.Subtract(new TimeSpan(1,0,0,0));
System.Diagnostics.Process youngestProccess = a.FirstOrDefault();


                foreach(var b in a){
                    if (b.StartTime > earliestStart)
                    {
                        earliestStart = b.StartTime;
                        youngestProccess = b;
                    }
                }                
                youngestProccess.Kill();
```

The code is working in the way that the most recent window "stop" working but the window is not beeing closed

Any idea?

Comment: Do you want to specifically close a window, close a tab, or close anything based on what the newest spawned IE process is?

Comment: it closed the tab but IE reopened it when I did it

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31098717/how-force-close-all-ie-processes-with-alert-on-form-unload can close all of them so it is doing what it should

Comment: Ths is a product that I am testing. The thing is that sometimes the "most recent window" opens like a tab (don't know why since I am following the same step) But, at least, in the task manager a tab or a window of IE are open as separate proccesses. So I just want to close the last IE proccess that was open, not all the windows

Comment: @Yoiku Interesting.  Consider whether you want to forcefully kill the tab/window or send a request to the application to close a tab/window.  What happens if the page open in IE invokes a beforeunload event?

My thought is that IE tries to autorecover the last session when the process is forcefully closed.  Surely there's a way to hook into IE and request a close programmatically.

Comment: I just tried to do a process.CloseMainWindow(); proccess.WaitForExit(60000); And it didn't work.

Comment: I just relized that that behavior of reopening the window happens only on iexplore.exe *32 proccess, and happens even manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I just discover how to solve the problem.

The message is being thrown because my IE has the option "Enable automatic crash recovery" checked in the Internet Options Advanced tab.

So if you face this you have 2 options: un-check that option forever (which might work for your case) or like in my case you can change the selection via registry keys and when you finish your testing return the value to be on.

So to do this you need to add this to your code before opening IE.

```
Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Recovery", "AutoRecover", 2);
```

To turn back on the option you must do the same but with a 0

```
Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Recovery", "AutoRecover", 0);
```